# Binary classifier Keras callback for sensitivity and specificity?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, scikit-learn, keras

How do I get sensitivity and specificity, when `class_mode='binary'`? - My current solution works for `class_mode='categorical'`:

```
from keras.callbacks import Callback
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix


class SensitivitySpecificityCallback(Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        if epoch:
            x_test, y_test = self.validation_data[0], self.validation_data[1]
            predictions = self.model.predict(x_test)
            output_sensitivity_specificity(epoch, predictions, y_test)


def output_sensitivity_specificity(epoch, predictions, y_test):
    y_test = np.argmax(y_test, axis=-1)
    predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=-1)
    c = confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions)
    print('Confusion matrix:\n', c)
    print('[{:03d}] sensitivity'.format(epoch), c[0, 0] / (c[0, 1] + c[0, 0]))
    print('[{:03d}] specificity'.format(epoch), c[1, 1] / (c[1, 1] + c[1, 0]))
```

[82 source lines full code example](https://gist.github.com/AlecTaylor/fe293d57c4ae1e79cc57c5bd19d0b5e4) (Python 2 & 3 compatible)

All the output is wrong:

```
Confusion matrix:
 [[40]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "network.py", line 118, in <module>
    callbacks=[SensitivitySpecificityCallback()], verbose=1)
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1426, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 229, in fit_generator
    callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
  File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 77, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
  File "network.py", line 56, in on_epoch_end
    output_sensitivity_specificity(epoch, predictions, y_test)
  File "network.py", line 64, in output_sensitivity_specificity
    print('[{:03d}] sensitivity'.format(epoch), c[0, 0] / (c[0, 1] + c[0, 0]))
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in binary mode you are essentially predicting one value which indicates the probability of positive class (i.e. binary classification), using `.argmax()` on predictions always return `0`. Therefore, you need to modify your `output_sensitivity_specificity` function for this case:

```
def output_sensitivity_specificity(epoch, predictions, y_test, mode='binary'):
    if mode == 'binary':
        # determine positive class predictions
        idx = predictions >= 0.5
        predictions = np.zeros(predictions.shape)
        predictions[idx] = 1
        # no need to modify y_test since it consists of zeros and ones already
    else:
        y_test = np.argmax(y_test, axis=-1)
        predictions = np.argmax(predictions, axis=-1)

    c = confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions)
    print('Confusion matrix:\n', c)
    print('[{:03d}] sensitivity'.format(epoch), c[0, 0] / (c[0, 1] + c[0, 0]))
    print('[{:03d}] specificity'.format(epoch), c[1, 1] / (c[1, 1] + c[1, 0]))
```

Just pass `mode=class_mode` when calling `output_sensitivity_specificity` in your callback and it would work for both binary and categorical modes.

Comment: Hmm, I tried that but got `IndexError: too many indices for array` at this line: `predictions[idx] = 1`

Comment: @AT Sorry, I can't test it right now. I must have made a silly mistake. Could you please print the shape of `predictions` and `idx` before the line that error occurs and tell me what they are?

Comment: @AT I edited my post. Just change `predictions = np.zeros((predictions.shape[0],))` to`predictions = np.zeros(predictions.shape)`.

Comment: @AT just curious, didn't it work for you? Does it still have problems?

Comment:  thanks, it worked. My network doesn't seem to be working with binary or categorical, so will ask a question on that one I have something intelligent to say 